# Makefile variable not set from grep output

Tags: variables, makefile, grep, pipe

I am trying to set the variable COGLINE to be the output of my grep line (which is searching my config.json file for the regExthe "cogs").  When I execute the grep line it correctly outputs the proper line number, but when I echo the variable it comes up blank.

```
COGLINE = $(grep -n \"cogs\" ~/Desktop/Repos/pronghorn/config.json | cut -f1 -d:)

all:
    grep -n \"cogs\" ~/Desktop/Repos/pronghorn/config.json | cut -f1 -d:
    echo $(COGLINE)
```

Here is the output:

```
GlennMBP:test glenn$ make all
grep -n \"cogs\" ~/Desktop/Repos/pronghorn/config.json | cut -f1 -d:
2
echo
```

You can see that the line number is properly found as "2", but the variable comes up blank as if it were not set.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is not a make function. That `COGLINE =` line is a make assignment.

You either need to use

```
COGLINE := $(shell grep -n \"cogs\" ~/Desktop/Repos/pronghorn/config.json | cut -f1 -d:)
```

if you want that run at make parse time and want it in a make variable.

Or

```
all:
        COGLINE=$$(grep -n \"cogs\" ~/Desktop/Repos/pronghorn/config.json | cut -f1 -d:); \
        echo "$${COGLINE}"
```

to run it at `all` recipe execution time and have it in a shell variable.

There are middle grounds as well but those are the two basic ideas.